# Getting No module named 'plotnine' error despite downloading plotnine package

Tags: python, plotnine

I downloaded plotnine using pip, and though the installation seemed successful, I still get a No module named 'plotnine' error while running my pythons script.

I have tried uninstalling SciPy, then reinstalling plotnine

My import statement looks like this

```py
import plotnine as p9
```

Comment: How did you install plotnine?

Comment: This often occurs when you have a system Python and another instance of Python that you installed aside of it. Are you in a similar situation?